# What component can I use to control the brightness of an LED strip?

Tags: led, resistance

I know that to adjust the brightness of a single LED, I can control the current using a resistor. What about for a strip of LEDs being fed by a 24V 1.8A power supply? I'd assume that the power being drawn would burn out a single resistor.

Comment: Do you want continuously variable brightness, or just want to set it to a fixed lower light level?

Comment: vary brightness. I can make do with switching between a few resistances or if a digital potentiometer is possible that would be great too.

Comment: OK one more question. What are the specs of your LED strip (actual current draw at 24V, number of LEDs per series string)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm not so sure of the specs. The part is a consumer product, an 'AeroGarden` with part number AG4501. The supplier doesn't provide any specs on the LEDS but rates the entire part as 45 Watts. There are 182 LEDs, 56 red 8 blue, and 118 white.

Answer (score 1):

The approach to take is use a power Nch fet to switch the low side 0V on and off with 5k to 10kHz PWM.  I*Rdson must be kept low to minimize heat rise.